# Microsoft SQL Server with Laravel 5

Tags: php, sql-server

I've just pushed a laravel application to an Ubuntu 16.04 VPS - the company is using SQL Server for record management - and I cannot get Laravel to connect to that database for authentication or anything else.

I'm getting errors that say that Laravel cannot find the drivers to connect.

I've searched in too many places.

There's no good tutorial that shows from start to finish, they're all using different packages and it's overwhelming.

Has anybody here successfully connected a laravel application (running on Ubuntu) to SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed using below configuration (on windows):

in .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=hots
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Database.php

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),
```

and in `connections`

```
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', ''),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'), // note the port
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],
```

Comment: That works fine on Windows XAMP, WAMP etc. -- I've also got something working on there. It's just when it's on Ubuntu (because I need to deploy this,) it doesn't seem to be working.